# sudo su command not working su: failed to execute root: No such file or directory

Tags: apt, upgrade, sudo, su

[su: failed to execute root: No such file or directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i1qw.png)

Comment: Possibly related:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/422712/sudo-su-in-bash-error-cannot-execute-help-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: May we see the output of `getent passwd root` please? I wonder if you somehow managed to set root's login shell to "root"

Comment: btw `sudo -i` or `sudo -s` are the preferred way to obtain a root shell

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by @steeldriver, your /etc/passwd probably has this as the first line:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:root
```

It should be replaced by something like:

```
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
```